# Get subject heading in Prestashop contact form email template

Tags: smarty, prestashop

I have a drop downselect for several subjects in my Prestashop contact form.

```
<select id="id_contact" name="id_contact" class="form-control" onchange="showElemFromSelect('id_contact', 'desc_contact')">
    <option value="0">-- Please chose --</option>
    <option value="1">Cancel order</option>
    <option value="3">Check order</option>
    <option value="2">Return a product</option>
</select>
```

Is there any possibility to create or to have the value of the subject chosen in the confirmation email received?:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you added this subjects as contacts names in backoffice, then in `controllers/front/ContactController` method `postProcess()` find block:

```
$var_list = array(
                                    '{order_name}' => '-',
                                    '{attached_file}' => '-',
                                    '{message}' => Tools::nl2br(stripslashes($message)),
                                    '{email}' =>  $from,
                                    '{product_name}' => '',
                                );
```

and add `$contact->name` e.g. to `{message}`

```
'{message}' => '<br />Subject: '. $contact->name . '<br />' .Tools::nl2br(stripslashes($message)),
```